# Why getting a type mismatch when using Collections.Sort method with a List<String?>?

Tags: android, kotlin

Why the following code failed to compile with the error:
"Type mismatch: inferred type is String? but Comparable<String?>! was expected
What does it mean the '!' after the brackets? And why it says that infered type is String
if it defiently MutableList<String?>?   ?

The code:

```
private fun createAllGamesList(gamesPerCountriesMap: MutableMap<String?, MutableMap<Long, MutableList<AllScoresGameObj>>>?)
            :List<BaseDataItem>
    {
        var countriesNameSet =  gamesPerCountriesMap?.keys
        var countriesNameList = countriesNameSet?.toMutableList()
        Collections.sort(countriesNameList)

        countriesNameList?.let{

        }


    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just want to point out that using the Java class Collections in Kotlin is kind of discouraged since the Kotlin standard library has built-in functions that can do the same tasks in ways that fit Kotlin-style syntax better, has better nullability handling, and can be more performant when they use inline lambdas.

For instance, you wouldn't be running into the weird type `Comparable<String?>!` if using Kotlin's `sort()` or `sortedBy()`. The `!` symbol after a type means it's maybe nullable and maybe not because the Java code doesn't specify either way.

In Kotlin, you can call `sort()` directly on your MutableList (it's an extension function) if it has a Comparable type. You'll still run into the problem that `String?` is not a `Comparable<String?>`, but you can do custom sorting using `compareBy` and `thenBy` to create a Comparator:

```
countriesNameList.sortedWith(
    compareBy<String?> { it ?: "" } // lambda returns String, which is Comparable
        .thenBy { it == null } // Sort between empty Strings and null values by returning a Boolean (another Comparable
)
```

Comment: thanks.  So if is *'!'* it means that it may be nullable or non nullable but if it is *'?'* it means it defiantly nullable? what is the difference? in both cases i need to treat it as nullable?

Comment: ? means it is forcing you to treat it as nullable and ! means it is not forcing you.

Comment: thanks. Is treat it as a nullable means to check against null in Kotlin code?

Comment: It means you can't call functions on it without the nullsafe operator (unless it's an extension function with nullable receiver). The reason for `!` is that Java doesn't have built-in nullability, so the compiler can't really guess if the type is nullable or not. In Java, it's typical to declare in the Javadocs whether a parameter or return type is allowed to be null, so if the Javadocs say it won't be null, you can safely omit null checks and the Kotlin compiler won't warn you. It also won't warn you about doing an unnecessary null check if you do check for null.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `countriesNameList` is a list of nullable Strings. That is, its type is `MutableList<String?>`, and not `MutableList<String>`.

`Collections.sort()` requires that the collection's type implement `Comparable<T>`, but `String?` does not implement `Comparable<String?>`. I imagine this is because it is not obvious where `null` values would fall in the natural ordering of `String?` elements.

This is very easy to observe with the following code:

```
val list: MutableList<String?> = mutableListOf("hello", "world")
Collections.sort(list)
```

If I change the type specification to not include the `?`, the problem goes away:

```
val list: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf("hello", "world")
Collections.sort(list)
```

You can work around this by providing your own comparator:

```
Collections.sort(countriesNameList) { lhs, rhs -> customCompare(lhs, rhs) }
```

```
private fun customCompare(lhs: String?, rhs: String?): Int = when {
    lhs == null && rhs == null -> 0
    lhs == null -> 1
    rhs == null -> -1
    else -> lhs.compareTo(rhs)
}
```

Comment: This version of `customCompare()` will push nulls to the end of the list. If you want them at the front of the list, swap the `1` and `-1` in the middle two cases.

Comment: thanks. But i want to improve the way i understand the editor/compiler. Can you please explain me what does it mean: " inferred type is String? but Comparable<String?>! " Does he ignores the fact that it is MutableList? And what is the meaning of !? i know it somehow related to platform type but can't understand what does it mean? It seems that the actual problem and when the compiler warning about are from two different world... In addition i will be happy to get an explanation why the two middle cases affect where the null will be at the of the sort.Is because of insertion sort way of work?